# Blank spaces inside Masonry column - React.JS, react-masonry-css and SCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, react-masonry

I'm doing a fetch list that return random card sizes with 2 widths:

- Horizontal (Larger)
- Default (Horizontal / 2)

And I'm getting blank spaces in masonry columns:

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUSwP.png)

I'm working with [react-masonry-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-css) and with this styles:

```
.masonry-grid {
display: flex;
gap: 1rem;
width: auto;
}

.masonry-grid_column {
background-clip: padding-box;
}

.masonry-grid_column > div {
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

I want to auto fill empty blank spaces with the next card if it fits inside the space and the next next card replace site of previous card.

[Expect Solution Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NHne.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added to masonry-grid_column class

```
{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: validate the answer if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

If you use Masonry component of `react-masonry-css`, you can use `breakpointCols` property.

```
const breakpointCols = {
  default: 2, // Number of columns for the default width
  600: 1,     // Number of columns for width less than 600px
};

<Masonry
  breakpointCols={breakpointCols}
  ...
>...</Masonry>
```

Just place cards in Masonry component, that way, you can see components placed in masonry mode without gaps.

Comment: I'm using that property, in the image is set as 2